# RESTFUL WCF Remove all xmlns

Tags: xml, wcf, rest, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I set my DataContracts namespace to "" which removed one namespace but I have to remove the other:

> xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

If theres no other way, how can I serialize my class prior to returning and hack out the namespace?

I have to do this to work with another companys API.

Comment: Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278569/how-to-remove-xml-namespace-when-return-type-is-generic-type-in-wcf-restful-serv/16675882#16675882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option, other than throwing away WCF is to change you service contract to return a stream and do the XML serialization yourself.  You could still use the data contract serializer, convert to a string strip out all the namespaces and then convert back to a stream to return, but that sounds nasty.

If you need to accept XML without namespaces in POST bodies then you are in for a whole lot more pain.  In that case I would dump WCF really quick.

Comment: I've already tested sending xml to my WCF without a namespace and it appears to have worked. I'll look into changing the service contract, thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what data type is the parameter that accepts the posted body?

Comment: When I tested I just posted a string in xml format without the namespace, the receiving function parameter object is a custom class which the xml gets serialized into... my data contract

Answer (score 0):

Try just removing the DataContract and DataMember attributes.  This may solve your problem.